# systemd-gpt-auto-generator doesn't mount EFI system partition

Tags: systemd, mount, partition, uefi, gpt

according to the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-gpt-auto-generator.html), the `systemd-gpt-auto-generator` should automatically find the EFI system partition and generate a mount unit to mount it on `/efi`. However this does not appear to work on my system, despite all the requirements being met.
I have an NVMe drive, `/dev/nvme0n1`, the EFI system partition is `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, and I'm using systemd-boot to boot the system

- There is a GPT partition table
- `/dev/nvme0n1p1` has the correct partition GUID code for EFI system partitions, `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`, and I can boot from it just fine
- The PARTUUID according to `blkid /dev/nvme0n1p1` is `6ebb8123-f305-404b-b5a3-65f46c7d7076`, and this matches the content of `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderDevicePartUUID-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f`
- I'm not booting in legacy (BIOS) mode
- The directory `/efi` exists on the root file system and it is empty
- no mount point for this partition is configured in `/etc/fstab`. There are no `.mount` units for it either
- there is no extended boot loader partition (XBOOTLDR)
- the generator is not disabled using the systemd.gpt_auto or rd.systemd.gpt_auto kernel cmdline parameter

I could just create an entry in `/etc/fstab` and be done with it, but I would rather understand why it's not working. Any pointers on how to debug this?

I've tried running the generator manually:

```
mkdir /tmp/{a,b,c}
SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug \
  /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-gpt-auto-generator /tmp/{a,b,c}
```

But the output doesn't contain anything useful:

```
Found container virtualization none.
Disabling root partition auto-detection, root= is defined.
dm-3: Not a partitioned device, ignoring: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, it's better to empty the old fstab file and use the systemd-gpt-auto-generator, using unit files if necessary.

Some ideas:

- fsck.vfat is missing ? (ie: Checking was requested for /dev/sdb1, but fsck.vfat does not exist.)
- efi.mount already exist (ie: Failed to create unit file efi.mount: File exists)
- your "/sysroot/"efi folder is not empty & /efi/.keep file is not present (ie: `"/efi" already populated, ignoring.`).

You could check

```bash
#search for dead unit with --all
systemctl list-units --all  --type=mount,automount 
  # efi.automount loaded    inactive dead    EFI System Partition Automount
 

mkdir /tmp/foo
SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-gpt-auto-generator /tmp/foo /tmp/foo /tmp/foo

systemctl status efi.automount
systemctl restart efi.automount

man systemd-gpt-auto-generator   
#not neeeded
systemctl edit efi.automount
```